# Resource ID in .net assemblies

Tags: .net, resources

Is there a way to get an icon resource Id from a .net exe or dll in c#? I am trying to register my application file type and can't find a way to extract the index of an image to be set as the default icon.

Comment: If you are not agreed, please specify why

Comment: There is no way to embed the unmanaged resources in managed application, so question is not correct. The Only way to fix it to use mixed-mode assembly such as C++/CLI assembly.

Comment: "There is no way to embed the unmanaged resources". You CAN embed images in a .NET application.The question is about the extraction of the image base on its index.